# PHP contact form in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I've installed a theme called PerfectCV. There's contact form in theme functions that I can't get working. In theme options I've added my email address but emails sent form the contact form seem not to be coming through.

I am new to programming but found the following in theme functions.php which deals with the contact form:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_action', 'pcv_sent_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_action', 'pcv_sent_email');

function pcv_sent_email(){

$pcv_name = $_POST['name'];
$pcv_email = $_POST['email'];
$pcv_message = $_POST['message'];
$pcv_to = $_POST['recipient_mail'];

$pcv_subject = __( 'Sent by CV Contact Form', 'perfectcv' );

$pcv_headers[] = __( 'From: ', 'perfectcv' ) . $pcv_name .' <'. $pcv_email .'>';

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );

if( wp_mail( $pcv_to, $pcv_subject, $pcv_message, $pcv_headers ) ) {
    echo __( 'Message sent!', 'perfectcv' );
} else {
    echo __( 'Message NOT sent!', 'perfectcv' );
}

die();

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Actually the form says that mail has been sent but they never come through. So no error messages.

Comment: http://oskari.uotinen.fi if you want to check the site itself.

Comment: Then you could probably check your mailer settings.

Comment: By mailer settings you mean?

Comment: I've not looked through the source but if there's no errors, it must be something to do with the method that actually sends the mail. Usually you'll need to adjust this server side or possibly in your WP settings.  Are you using localhost or an SMTP server for example?

Comment: Actually this is something I don't know. There's no option about email server.

Comment: Try something like this: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/test-email-sending/

Answer (score 1):

WP-Mail-SMTP plugin solved my problem. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I'm using the same theme and this plugin, but I can't get the from-address working: it always uses the fixed from-address that is used to login into the smtp server. Is it working correctly for you? As it is, all mails people send me seem to come from my own address...

Answer (score 0):

That particular template uses the php mail() function and the default email address you have set in Wordpress settings->email. There are no other configurations.

Make sure the email address that's there actually exists and is configured on your server. You can check this in your site's cpanel.

If the address does not exist, or it's not the one you want to use, you can change it in the settings panel. Again, make sure the address exists in your cpanel or add it if it does not.